# PATH not recognizing additions to it

Tags: windows, path, cmd

```
C:\Users\jamiller>PATH
PATH=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;

C:\Users\jamiller>msbuild
'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\jamiller>cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>msbuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.33440
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34014]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory     does not contain a project or solution file.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> wat
```

Anyone know why PATH isn't recognizing executables that are inside of its directories?

Comment: Have you tried with an ending \ ? It's also possible that you need to restart (or open a new cmd from the current one) to be able to see the changes to PATH.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that you don't have `C:\Windows\system32` in your PATH.  Also, make sure you have `.EXE` in your PATHEXT.